# Apply operator to certain functions

Tags: pattern-matching

I have the following term

```
  a[om1] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4] f1[om1] f2[om2] f3[om3] f4[om4]
```

I want to apply an operator `<...>` to it that acts only on the functions `f` but not on `a,b,c,d`.

I want to to it with pattern matching. The result should be

```
  a[om1] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4] <f1[om1] f2[om2] f3[om3] f4[om4]>
```

The operator is defined with `\[LeftAngleBracket]` and `\[RightAngleBracket]`. The functions `f...` always have the given name structure (but the numbers can vary). How can I exploit this?

Answer (score 1):

If the functions `f1`, `f2`, etc. form a finite set which is known beforehand, then the following seems to do the trick.

```
expr = a[om1] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4] f1[om1] f2[om2] f3[om3] f4[om4];
expr /. x:HoldPattern[Times[Longest[Alternatives[_f1, _f2, _f3, _f4]..]]] :> \[LeftAngleBracket]x\[RightAngleBracket]
(*Returns a[om1] \[LeftAngleBracket]f1[om1] f2[om2] f3[om3] f4[om4]\[RightAngleBracket] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4]*)
```

For use with `Replace` and arbitrary level spec the rule must be slightly modified:

```
Replace[
  expr,
  Times[r_., x : Longest[Alternatives[_f1, _f2, _f3, _f4] ..]] :> r \[LeftAngleBracket]x\[RightAngleBracket],
  {0}
]
(*Returns a[om1] \[LeftAngleBracket]f1[om1],f2[om2],f3[om3],f4[om4]\[RightAngleBracket] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = a[om1] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4] f1[om1] f2[om2] f3[om3] f4[om4];

Format[foo[x_], StandardForm] := AngleBracket[x] 
(Times @@ #2) foo[Times @@ #] & @@ GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard[List @@ expr, 
   (StringStartsQ["f"][SymbolName @ Head[#]]) &]
```

> a[om1] b[om2] c[om3] d[om4] 〈f1[om1] f2[om2] f3[om3] f4[om4]〉